# Symplifying a cost function of an optimization problem

Tags: geometry, optimization, vectors

**Background**

I have a zero-mean dataset $D(\theta)$ composed by $m$ vectors $y_{1}(\theta)$, $y_2(\theta)$, $\dots$, $y_{m}(\theta)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.
Each observation $y_i(\theta)$ depends on a unknown rotation angle $\theta$, which I want to estimate.
Given the dataset, I'm able to compute two vectors $g_N(\theta), g_S(\theta) \in\mathbb{R}^2$ which have the following properties:

- regardless the value of $\theta$, the two vectors $g_N(\theta), g_S(\theta)$ are non-null;
- regardless the value of $\theta$, the two vectors $g_N(\theta), g_S(\theta)$ belong to a line passing through the origin. In particular, holds
  \begin{equation*} g_N(\theta) = -s(\theta)\,g_S(\theta) \end{equation*}
  where the scaling factor $s(\theta)$ changes with $\theta$ and, regardless the value of $\theta$, is positive.
- regardless $\theta$, the vertical component $\eta_N(\theta)$ of $g_N(\theta)$ is non-negative while the vertical component $\eta_S(\theta)$ of $g_S(\theta)$ is non-positive.
- in the special cases $\theta = 0$ or $\theta = \pi$, two magic things happen: (1) the scaling factor simplifies to $s=1$; (2) the horizontal component $\xi_N(\theta)$ of $g_N(\theta)$ and the horizontal component $\xi_S(\theta)$ of $g_S(\theta)$ vanish.

My idea to estimate $\theta$ takes advantage of the two special cases $\theta=0, \pi$: I deliberately counter-rotate the dataset $D(\theta)$ of an angle $\varphi$, to get $D(\theta-\varphi)$. If I find $\varphi$ such that $g_N$ and $g_S$ are"opposite and vertical" (in the sense previously explained), then I know $\theta-\varphi = 0$ or $\theta-\varphi = \pi$, and so I can say that the angle $\theta$ is $\varphi$ or $\varphi+\pi$. Clearly there is still the ambiguity about the offset $\pi$, but this is another problem which I don't want to discuss here.

So, I formalize the estimation process as the following optimization problem
\begin{equation*}
\hat{\theta} = \arg\min_{\varphi \in [0,2\pi)} \underbrace{|\eta_N(\theta-\varphi)+\eta_S(\theta-\varphi)|}_{\triangleq c_1(\varphi)}+\underbrace{|\xi_N(\theta-\varphi)|+|\xi_S(\theta-\varphi)|}_{\triangleq c_2(\varphi)}
\end{equation*}
where the second term $c_2(\varphi)$ penalizes $\varphi$ that does not put $g_N$ and $g_S$ on the vertical axis, $c_1(\varphi)$ penalizes $\varphi$ that does not symmetrize $g_N$ and $g_S$ (given that the horizontal component are equal).

**Question**

Is there a more simple cost that encodes the fact that $g_N$ and $g_S$ must be opposite vectors belonging to the vertical axis?